# Passive "to+infinitive" in the context: usage and definition

Tags: passive-voice, to-infinitive

Consider ([source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA6-PR78&dq=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20sojourning%20in%20Panama&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj09pjRv4nOAhULbxQKHYACDNwQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20sojourning%20in%20Panama&f=false)):

> At that moment Francisco Pizarro came onto the scene. A native of Spain, he was sojourning in Panama when he heard of the riches **to be found** in that far off land.

**My Question:** How should I construe **"riches to be found"**?

---

I analyzed this sentence as:

1. He heard of riches that people were to find.
2. He heard of riches to be found (by people).

Am I right? Does it a furtive **"to+infinitive"**? I am wondering what is the difference if we say

> He was sojourning in Panama when he heard of the riches **being found** in that far off land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he heard of the riches **to be found** in that far off land

"riches to be found" implies that there should be riches, but they were not found yet. Same idea as:

> I heard that the lottery has money **to be won**.

I just haven't won any so far.

> he heard of the riches **being found** in that far off land.

implies the riches were already found, or at least someone said so.

> I heard of the lottery **being won** by my ex. Tough luck.